# Best open source DB technology to store and query large, sparse matrices

Tags: storage, table, olap

I have a large vector space model, in which each point is a multi-variate observation. In other words, I have a large number of pretty large records, mostly of ints and floats. I started with in-memory matrices, but given a large number of points (1B+) and a large number of dimensions (1K+), I soon realized that that wasn't an option.

I need to

1) make the whole thing persistent and dynamic (I want to add/update/remove points/dimensions easily)

2) query the VSM efficiently, performing similarity queries (given a point, find top K similar points) and range queries (find all points within a subspace).

Based on some reading, it seems that there isn't an off-the-shelf package to do this. What would you use to implement this kind of scenario? Dumping each point as a row in a relational db didn't work because the large number of dimensions. Even after normalization, the relational db was clearly too slow to perform similarity queries.

Moreover, I need to compute the dot product on chunks of the matrix.
What technology would you recommend in this case? For example, I have read about array databases, and OLAP cubes, but I would like to have some advice from real DBAs.

Thanks, Mulone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [SciDB](http://www.scidb.org/) - a database designed for precisely this use case. It has as as its major driver [Michael Stonebraker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Stonebraker), a man who knows a lot about databases - it would be an exaggeration to say that he's been involved with more database systems than most people have had hot dinners, but not by much :-)!

> "including Ingres, Illustra, Cohera, StreamBase Systems, Vertica,
>   VoltDB, and Paradigm4. He was previously the Chief Technical Officer
>   (CTO) of Informix. He is also an editor for the book Readings in
>   Database Systems".

Google "michael stonebraker scidb sparse matrix" and subsets thereof and I think that it might be a good fit for what you want.